# Python - El parámetro 'message' de la función on_message de discord.py imprime un texto vacío y no sé por qué

Tags: python, discord.py, bot

Estoy haciendo un bot simple con python para discord que lea información de una API y la publique, aunque eso es para más adelante, ahora mismo lo que pretendo es simplemente que si recibe en el servidor la palabra !almanax, envíe un texto al canal del servidor
La cosa es que la librería de discord incluye sus propias funciones siendo una de ellas `async def on_message(message)` siendo message el texto que introduce el usuario por el canal de discord,
pues bien, si yo pongo un print de message.content y escribo en el servidor un simple 'hola mundo', por consola me imprime un texto vacío, es decir, **está escuchando bien el evento, pero no está tomando correctamente el parámetro,** alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?
Os adjunto el código

```
import discord
import requests
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN_BOT")


intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content) # <-- esto debería imprimir lo que el usuario escriba, imprime texto vacío
    if message.content.startswith("!almanax"):
        almanax = obtener_almanax() #esta función la tengo a parte, no es importante para este post
        print(almanax)
        if almanax is not None:
            await message.channel.send('hola buenas tardes')
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Ha habido un error al obtener la información del Almanax.")
    else: 
        print('nothing here')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Como el texto lo toma vacío, nunca entra en la condición del if, y devuelve por consola un 'nothing here', la condición del else.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que está en rojo es el primer print de la cadena de texto vacía.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Haz intentado imprimir únicamente `message` en lugar de `message.content`? O tal vez `print(vars(message))` para ve que contiene?

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato sí, y al imprimir message, me imprime el objeto entero aunque veo que no existe la propiedad content, pero igualmente debería de funcionar, estoy leyendo la referencia de la api de discord https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content parece que tengo que habilitar un intent_message_content primero, que no sé que es jeje me toca investigarlo

Answer (score 1):

Pues leyendo e informándome sobre la API de discord ya he obtenido la solución, así que me autorespondo al post por si a alguien en un futuro le ocurre igual y necesita ayuda.

Lo primero en este enlace dice que para tomar el valor correctamente de la función on_message, se necesita habilitar `Intents.message_content`, de lo contrario imprimirá una cadena vacía, sorpresa, lo que me pasaba.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content

En el código en python, habría que poner:

```
intents.message_content = True
```

Luego en la página web de discord donde creamos el bot y le damos permisos y demás, en la pestaña de bot, hay que habilitar una función que yo tenía deshabilitada previamente, adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras esto el código ya imprimirá bien el mensaje de texto que recibe desde el servidor de discord, y en función de eso, seguir ejecutando el código.

Reiniciar el script de python y listo.

Un saludo y feliz año nuevo.